# Closing my basement vent

Tags: ducts, blocking

I am in the process of setting up electric baseboard heaters in my basement and I have 3 vents that runs from my furnace.  Can I block those vent ducts?

Comment: Reason for not using the furnace.  Baseboard heaters are cheap to buy, but you pay a lot on your electric bill.  A mini split system costs more to buy but runs much cheaper.  The vents should be able to be closed/blocked off.

Comment: Is "blocking" closing the louvers on the vents, stuffing a piece of cardboard in the end of duct behind the vent, or drywalling over it as though it never existed? The latter 2 might have an impact on the balance of airflow throughout the house and you might not like the results too much.

Comment: Are we talking about air outlets that the furnace used to heat the basement room where the baseboard heaters are being added, or about vents that go from the furnace area to outdoors?